# Scrollbar direction inverted when using a stylus in Chrome

Tags: html, css, scroll, stylus-pen

Scrollbars generated by CSS-"overflow" work as usual with the mouse but work in an inverted direction when using a stylus. With a stylus, the handle of such a scrollbar cannot be dragged at all. This happens even with scrollbars of Chrome's developer tools itself (console, source code, etc.). And it happens in Edge as well (and in its developer tools), with a Wacom pen display and on a notebook computer with N-Trig stylus (Windows 10, newest Chrome and Edge, newest Wacom driver).

On the track of the scrollbar, the stylus seems to drag the document, just as though it was placed on the document and not on the scrollbar. On the scrollbar's handle this would counteract the handle's regular motion; that could explain why the handle does not move.

Is there a way to change that behavior?

Here is a minimal demonstration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .a {
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    .b {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
      <p>abc</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem with the Chrome browser with a Wacom PTH-650 digitizer on Windows 11. This problem doesn't occur in Firefox.

The problem probably stems from an interaction between Chrome and [Microsoft's Windows Ink](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-the-pen-menu-in-windows-701b15d4-2dcc-1aec-cf2b-370c56e8baf4#WindowsVersion=Windows_10). Windows has it's own system for supporting pens and by default Wacom tablets redirect their input to this system.

You can however switch off *Windows Ink* For Chrome. This is how to do that:

- Make sure Chrome is running.
- Go to the Wacom Tablet Properties panel. Select your tablet and pen.
- Next to the "Applications" row, press on the "+" button and select Chrome. You should now see Chrome separately in the applications.
- Make sure Chrome is selected in the applications row.
- Go to the "Mapping" tab and unselect the "Use Windows Ink" at the bottom.

Now test the scrolling in Chrome. Did it help?

The reason you shouldn't untick Windows Ink for all applications is because in most modern applications something like pressure sensitivity relies only on Windows Ink and doesn't connect directly to the Wacom driver anymore.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks, that did it, at least for the Wacom device. As the Wacom setting was hard to find for me in German, here are the details: Open "Wacom Tablett-Eigenschaften"; have Chrome running; to the right of the row "Anwendungen" click on "+"; in the dialog that appears select Chrome; go to the tab "Kalibrieren" (of all places) and deselect "Windows Freihand verwenden". I guess this needs to be filed as a Chromium bug?

Comment: On the notebook computer with the N-Trig stylus I don't seem to be able to get rid of Windows Ink. Setting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsInkWorkspace\AllowWindowsInkWorkspace to zero only seems to hide the ink menu on the task bar; no improvement on the scroll bars. So I'll have to switch to Firefox on that machine.

Comment: Ouch in hindsight! No, the described Wacom setting does _not_ work! With it, pointer events of pointer type "pen" become pointer events of type "mouse". So for me this means a switch to Firefox on all machines.

Comment: @user22495 This doesn't happen to me, the pen keeps working like normal. Make sure you have the correct settings. See the image I added to my answer: 1. Untick "Use Windows Ink" and 2. Select "Pen Mode".

Comment: @user22495 I do understand the problems translating things from English to German. I am Dutch, but as you can see I installed an English version of Windows 11, because I ran into these language difference all the time when communicating with other programmers.

Comment: I have version 6.4.5-2 of the Wacom control panel (which ought to be the newest one) and the third tab looks completely different from yours (apart from the Windows Ink checkbox). In particular, there is no Mode: Pen/Mouse setting. I use a Cintiq 27QHDT. Maybe, the settings are different for displays as opposed to display-less graphics tablets.

Comment: @user22495: Yes, for Wacom displays the setting are different. I don't have a Cintiq here, at the moment, so I can't test one.